# Heroku container release error when using docker

Tags: docker, heroku

I am using docker and heroku. I am trying to release my image to heroku but no luck.
i get an error message:

That says: `You do not have access to the app my app.`

my steps were:

```
- heroku login 
- heroku container:login 
- docker build -t registry.heroku.com/myapp/web . 
- docker push registry.heroku.com/myapp/web 
- heroku container:release web -a myapp
```

Everything is going fine until I get to the last line.
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the name is already taken by someone else and you (obviously) do not have access.
Display the list of your applications (verify `myapp` is not be there)

```
heroku apps
```

Create a new app with a unique name

```
heroku create mydemoapp_v10
```